# Weekly / Monthly Time Reports in Outlook for several categories

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, report

I want to extract the time spent (weekly and monthly) in Outlook Calendar for different categories to extract reports.

I found this code with which I tried to play a bit with the goal to summarize the information for the whole calendar in an excel worksheet:

```
Sub ExportTimeSpentOnAppointmentsInEachColorCategory()
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim objAppointments As Outlook.Items
    Dim objAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim strCategory As String
    Dim arrCategory As Variant
    Dim varCategory As Variant
    Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim arrKey As Variant
    Dim arrItem As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nLastRow As Integer

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objAppointments = Application.Session.PickFolder.Items

    For Each objAppointment In objAppointments
        arrCategory = Split(objAppointment.Categories, ",")
        For Each varCategory In arrCategory
            strCategory = Trim(varCategory)
            If objDictionary.Exists(strCategory) Then
               objDictionary.Item(strCategory) = objDictionary.Item(strCategory) + objAppointment.Duration
            Else
               objDictionary.Add strCategory, objAppointment.Duration
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Create a new Excel workbook
    Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    objExcelApp.Visible = True
    objExcelWorkbook.Activate

    With objExcelWorksheet
         .Cells(1, 1) = "Color Category"
         .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
         .Cells(1, 1).Font.Size = 14
         .Cells(1, 2) = "Total Time (min)"
         .Cells(1, 2).Font.Bold = True
         .Cells(1, 2).Font.Size = 14
    End With

    arrKey = objDictionary.Keys
    arrItem = objDictionary.Items

    For i = LBound(arrKey) To UBound(arrKey)
        nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        objExcelWorksheet.Cells(nLastRow, 1) = arrKey(i)
        objExcelWorksheet.Cells(nLastRow, 2) = arrItem(i)
    Next

    objExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
End Sub
```

How can I modify this code to generate this report for a given week or month (e.g. January 2020).

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

If you do not know where to start with a problem, searching for blocks of code that might contain relevant code can be a good start.  But you need to mine that code for useful nuggets.  Simply trying to adapt that code to your problem is not going to work nor is asking someone else to adapt it.

What do you need to know?  My initial list is:

1. How to find the calendar items for the period I wish to analyse?
2. How do I sort those calendar items by category?
3. How do I create a new Excel workbook or how do I update an existing workbook?
4. How do I arrange the information within the workbook in a useful manner?

This is not a complete list.  For example: how does the user specify the required date range?  I am not going to worry about such issues while I investigate the more difficult issues.  Your code relates to need 2 so I will concentrate on need 1.

If there are any good Outlook VBA tutorials on calendars, I have not found them.  Everything I know is the result of experimentation.

I created some appointments in the future, so they did not get confused with my real appointments.  I used all the options within Create Appointment that were of interest to me.  I created single appointments for different periods within same day, all day events, appointments that started on one day and ended on another.  I created recurrent entries for every available period, for a fixed number of occurrences, until a given date or for ever.  I then altered or deleted single occurrences.

I started with the object model for appointment items.  I wrote a routine that looped down my appointment items outputting the properties that looked interesting.  I learnt about the different type of appointment item and which properties went with which type.  The routines below are the result of my experimentation.

The first thing I learnt was that my calendar was not where I expected it to be.  This routine helps with that problem:

```
Sub CalendarDtls()

  Dim InxFldrCrnt As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long

  With Application.Session
    Debug.Print "Store containing default calendar: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Name
    Debug.Print "Name of default calendar: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Name
    Debug.Print "Items in default calendar: " & .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Count

    For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
      With .Folders(InxStoreCrnt)
        For InxFldrCrnt = 1 To .Folders.Count
          If LCase(Left$(.Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Name, 8)) = "calendar" Then
            Debug.Print .Name & "\" & .Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Name & "  Items: " & _
                        .Folders(InxFldrCrnt).Items.Count
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End With
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

The above is an Outlook macro that displays details of the default calendar and of every calendar it can find.

When I started writing Outlook macros, I soon learnt how quickly the number of macros can grow and how difficult it can be to find the macro you want to look at today.  I have lots of modules with meaningful names.  My calendar experiments are in module ModCalendar.  (Use F4 to access the Properties Window to rename modules.)  I have no operational code in ModCalendar; operational code is held in modules with names like ModTaskName.  I suggest you do something similar and place the above macro and the next one in a module named ModCalendar or something similar.  Do not forget to include `Option Explicit` as the first statement.

Now consider this macro:

```
Sub DspCalendarItems()

  ' Create programmer-friendly list of items in selected calendar
  ' in desktop file Appointments.txt.
  'Developed as aid to understanding Outlook calendars.

  Dim ItemCrnt As Object
  Dim ItemCrntClass As Long
  Dim FileOut As Object
  Dim FolderSrc As MAPIFolder
  Dim Fso As FileSystemObject
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RecurrPattCrnt As RecurrencePattern

  Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

  Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set FileOut = Fso.CreateTextFile(Path & "\Appointments.txt", True)

  With Application.Session

    'Set FolderSrc = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set FolderSrc = .Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Calendar")
    FileOut.WriteLine ("Number of items: " & FolderSrc.Items.Count)

    For Each ItemCrnt In FolderSrc.Items

      With ItemCrnt

        ' Occasionally I get syncronisation
        ' errors.  This code avoids them.
        ItemCrntClass = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        ItemCrntClass = .Class
        On Error GoTo 0

        ' I have never found anything but appointments in
        ' Calendar but test just in case
        If ItemCrntClass = olAppointment Then

          Select Case .RecurrenceState
            Case olApptException
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Recurrence state is Exception")
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.WriteLine ("All day " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                Debug.Assert False
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                End If
              Else
                ' Different start and end dates.
                FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              End If
              Debug.Assert False
            Case olApptMaster
              Set RecurrPattCrnt = .GetRecurrencePattern
              Debug.Assert Year(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Year(.Start)
              Debug.Assert Month(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Month(.Start)
              Debug.Assert Day(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate) = Day(.Start)
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day ")
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                'Debug.Assert False
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " ")
                  'Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " ")
                  Debug.Assert False
                End If
              ElseIf DateDiff("d", .Start, .End) = 1 And Format(.Start, "hh:mm") = "00:00" And _
                                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") = "00:00" Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day ")
                'Debug.Assert False
              Else
                ' Have not thought repeating multi-day appointments through
                Debug.Assert False
                FileOut.Write ("XXX From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              End If
              Select Case RecurrPattCrnt.RecurrenceType
                Case olRecursDaily
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("daily")
                Case olRecursMonthly
                  Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("monthly")
                Case olRecursMonthNth
                  Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("nth monthly")
                Case olRecursWeekly
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("weekly")
                Case olRecursYearly
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  FileOut.Write ("yearly")
              End Select  ' RecurrPattCrnt.RecurrenceType
              FileOut.Write (" from " & Format(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternStartDate, "ddd d mmm yy"))
              If Year(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternEndDate) = 4500 Then
                ' For ever
                'Debug.Assert False
              Else
                FileOut.Write (" to " & Format(RecurrPattCrnt.PatternEndDate, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              End If
            Case olApptNotRecurring
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                FileOut.Write ("All day " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              ElseIf Day(.Start) = Day(.End) Then
                ' Appointment starts and finishes on same day
                If Format(.Start, "hh:mm") <> Format(.End, "hh:mm") Then
                  ' Different start and end times on same day
                  FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " to " & _
                                           Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  'Debug.Assert False
                Else
                  ' Start and end time the same
                  FileOut.Write ("At " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                  'Debug.Assert False
                End If
              Else
                ' Different start and end dates.
                FileOut.Write ("From " & Format(.Start, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.Start, "ddd d mmm yy") & " to " & _
                                         Format(.End, "hh:mm") & " on " & Format(.End, "ddd d mmm yy"))
                'Debug.Assert False
              End If
            Case olApptOccurrence
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Occurrence")
              Debug.Assert False
            Case Else
              Debug.Print ("Unknown recurrence state " & .RecurrenceState)
              Debug.Assert False
              FileOut.WriteLine ("Unknown recurrence state " & .RecurrenceState)
          End Select  ' .RecurrenceState
          If .Subject <> "" Then
            FileOut.Write ("  " & .Subject)
          Else
            FileOut.Write ("  ""No subject""")
          End If
          If .Location <> "" Then
            FileOut.Write (" at " & .Location)
          Else
            FileOut.Write (" at undefined location")
          End If
          FileOut.WriteLine ("")
          If .Body <> "" Then
            FileOut.WriteLine ("  Body: " & .Body)
          End If

        End If ' ItemCrntClass = olAppointment

      End With  ' ItemCrnt

    Next ItemCrnt

  End With  ' Application.Session

  FileOut.Close

End Sub
```

Near the top of the above macro, you will find:

```
'Set FolderSrc = .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set FolderSrc = .Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Calendar")
```

If your appointments are in the default calendar, remove the quote from the first line and add one to the second.  If your appointments are NOT in the default calendar, `CalendarDtls()` will have output something like:

```
Store containing default calendar: a.j.dallimore@MyIsp.com
Name of default calendar: Calendar (This computer only)
Items in default calendar: 0
a.j.dallimore@MyIsp.com @virginmedia.com\Calendar (This computer only)  Items: 0
Outlook Data File\Calendar  Items: 180
```

Find the row with a non-zero value for Items and copy the store name (Outlook Data File for me) and the folder name (Calendar for me) to the second line.

Run this macro and study the output.  Where does it get the values it displays?  Most appointment items have the same properties, but those properties will not have sensible values for inappropriate items.  How has the macro decided what properties to display and what not to display?  Add display of categories.  I was not interested in categories so the macro does not display them.

This macro is basic.  It does not touch complicated issues like exceptions.  I believe it will be a good start of understanding how to identify the appointments that fall within the report period.

I have discovered a bug in the next macro I wish to share.  I will add this macro when I have fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

My total answer exceeds StackOverflow's limit of 30,000 characters so I have split the answer into two

**Part 2**

On more detailed checking, I found my second macro did not contain a bug; it was unfinished.  My guess is I developed it far enough to discover what I needed to know and then abandoned it.

I have now finished that macro.  It probably contains everything you need for the first issue on my list: How to find the calendar items for the period I wish to analyse?

Finding the calendar items you wish to analyse is trickier than you might expect.  A one-off meeting will result in a single `AppointmentItem` in your calendar. That `AppointmentItem` will contain everything you need to know about the meeting.  In particular, it contains properties Start and End which will allow a simple check against the report range.  It is recurring appointments that are tricky.

Suppose I have regular team meetings on Tuesday and Thursday.  I will go to my calendar and create an appointment for Thursday, 2 January 2020.  I will enter the title, location, categories.  I will then click [Recurrence].  I will click (Weekly) if it is not already selected as the Recurrence pattern.  Thursday will be ticked.  I will tick Tuesday.  I will change the End date to Thursday, 31 December 2020.  My calendar now shows appointments for every Tuesday and Thursday for the entire year.  I have holidays booked for June, so I will delete the relevant entries.  Later, I receive a message saying a particular meeting is to be half-an-hour later than normal and in a different meeting room.  I will change the details for relevant day.

If a VBA macro looks at my calendar, it will find a single Master appointment for 2 January 2020.  A Master appointment is one that recurs.  The macro uses `GetRecurrencePattern()` to get the details of how the appointment recurs.  The recurrence pattern also records all the exceptions.

The 100 or so entries on my calendar, have been generated from one `AppointmentItem`.  To decide which of these entries are within the report period, my macro generates an array containing 5 and 2.  It starts with Thursday 2 January 2020, then steps forward 5 days then 2 days then 5 days then 2 days then 5 days and so on until it is past the report period.  The 5-day step takes it from Thursday to Tuesday.  The 2-day step takes it from Tuesday to Thursday.  The macro checks every date against the report period.  If the date is within the report period, the macro checks for an exception.  If there is no exception for the date, the macro adds a regular entry to the collection `AppointToReport`.  An exception can be a delete of an occurrence or a change to an occurrence.  For a delete, the macro does not add to the collection.  For a change, it adds an entry based on the exception.

If that last paragraph was confusing, you will have to create some test appointments and step through the macro and study what it does.

I said at the beginning that I start with the object model for an `AppointmentItem`.  This is a useful start, but it does not say which properties are used with which recurrence patterns.  To discover that I use Watch.  You will find [Watch Window] under [View] and [Add Watch] under [Debug].  I added the variables holding the `AppointmentItem` and the `RecurrencePattern`.  This allowed me to understand how each property was used under different circumstances.

The macro below is an Excel macro.  When you want to move data from Outlook to Excel, it can be difficult to decide whether to write the macro within Outlook or Excel since the code is very similar with both approaches.  Outlook has a robust security system that does not like outside macros accessing its database, so the user must give permission at least once every 10 minutes.  It does not worry about an Excel macro reading appointments, so that is not a consideration for you.  For me, the biggest considerations are: (1) I find the Excel VBA development environment slightly easier than the Outlook development environment and (2) it is easier to share Excel macros with colleagues than Outlook macros.

If you really want an Outlook macro, you will have to recode the start of my macro.

I said earlier, the macro adds an entry to a collection for every event within the report range.  When it has checked the entire calendar, it outputs the contents of that collection to a worksheet.  For my test data, output is

[image: Output to worksheet for my test data]

The entries in the collection contain Start, End, Subject, Location and Categories.  You can easily add more values if necessary.  Note that the events are listed in the order added to the calendar.  I added some appointments with categories first then appointments that used as many recurrence options as I thought I ought to test.  If I understand correctly, you want to sum the total time per category so the sequence should not matter.  You should test the macro will all `AppointmentItem` options you use.

I have left all my testing code within the macro but have commented it out.  You can remove the quotes if you want to restore the output.  I place `Debug.Assert False` at the top of every path through my code.  When that path is executed, I comment the `Debug.Assert False` out.  If you find a `Debug.Assert False` without a quote, it means the code below it has not been tested.

```
Option Explicit
Sub InvestigateCalendar()

  ' Outputs major properties of all calendar items within a calendar for a
  ' specified date range to desktop file "Calendar.txt".  The objective is
  ' to better understand calendar itens and how they link.

  ' Requires reference to Microsoft Outlook nn.n Library
  ' where "nn.n" identifies the version of Office you are using.

  ' Specify date range to be reported on
  Const DateReportStart As Date = #3/1/2020#
  Const DateReportEnd As Date = #3/31/2020#

  Dim AllDayEvent As Boolean
  Dim AppointCrnt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
  Dim AppointToReport As New Collection
  Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application
  Dim CalItemClass As Long
  Dim Categories As String
  Dim DateAddInterval As String
  Dim DateAddNumbers As Variant
  Dim DateCrnt As Date
  Dim DateEnd As Date
  Dim DateStart As Date
  Dim DayOfWeekMaskValues As Variant
  Dim ExceptionAllDayEvent As Boolean
  Dim ExceptionDateEnd As Date
  Dim ExceptionDateStart As Date
  Dim ExceptionLocation As String
  Dim ExceptionNoneForDateCrnt As Boolean
  Dim ExceptionSubject As String
  Dim FldrCal As Outlook.Folder
  Dim InxATR As Long                     ' Index into AppointToReport array
  Dim InxDAN As Long                     ' Index into DateAddNumbers array
  Dim InxDCrnt As Long                   ' Index into day of week arrays
  Dim InxDEnd As Long                    ' End value for InxDCrnt
  Dim InxDStart As Long                  ' Start value for InxDCrnt
  Dim InxE As Long                       ' Index into exceptions
  Dim InxFC As Long                      ' Index into Calendar folder
  Dim IntervalNext As Long
  Dim Location As String
  Dim MaskCrnt As Long
  Dim NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask As Long
  Dim OccurrenceInRange As Boolean
  Dim PathDesktop As String
  Dim RecurrPattern As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
  Dim RowCrnt As Long
  Dim Subject As String

  PathDesktop = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")

  ' Use this Set if the calendar of interest is the default calendar.
  'Set FldrCal = AppOutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

  ' Use this Set to access a named calendar
  Set FldrCal = AppOutlook.Session.Folders("Outlook Data File").Folders("Calendar")
  ' Change above as necessary

  '' Values returned by function Weekday for Sunday to Saturday
  'WeekDayValues = VBA.Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  ' Values In DayOfWeekMask for Sunday to Saturday
  DayOfWeekMaskValues = VBA.Array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64)

  ' This loop reviews the entire calendar and identifies Calendar Items
  ' that fall entirely or partially within the report period. All such
  ' Calendar Items are recorded in collection AppointToReport.

  For InxFC = 1 To FldrCal.Items.Count

    ' Occasionally I get syncronisation errors.  This code avoids them.
    CalItemClass = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    CalItemClass = FldrCal.Items(InxFC).Class
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' I have never found anything but appointment items in
    ' Calendar but test just in case
    If CalItemClass = olAppointment Then
      Set AppointCrnt = FldrCal.Items(InxFC)
      With AppointCrnt
        Select Case .RecurrenceState
          Case olApptNotRecurring
            'Debug.Assert False

            'Debug.Assert .Subject <> "All day non-recurring"
            'Debug.Assert .Subject <> "All day meeting"

            If (.Start >= DateReportStart And .Start <= DateReportEnd) Or _
               (.End >= DateReportStart And .End <= DateReportEnd) Then
              'Debug.Assert False
              ' Either the start of the appointment is within the report range
              ' or the end of the appointment is with the report range or
              ' both start and end are within the report range
              'AppointToReport.Add Array(.Start, .End, .Subject, .Location, .Categories)
              AppointToReport.Add Array( _
                                    CalcStartDateCrnt(.Start, .Start, .AllDayEvent), _
                                    CalcEndDateCrnt(.Start, .End, .Start, .AllDayEvent), _
                                    .Subject, .Location, .Categories)
            Else
              If .AllDayEvent Then
                'Debug.Assert False
                If DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(.Start)) = DateValue(.End) Then
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  'Debug.Print "Non-recurring Out-of-range all day " & DateValue(.Start)
                Else
                  Debug.Assert False
                  Debug.Print "Non-recurring Out-of-range all day" & _
                              DateValue(.Start) & "-" & DateValue(.End)
                End If
              Else
                If DateValue(.Start) = DateValue(.End) Then
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  'Debug.Print "Non-recurring Out-of-range " & DateValue(.Start) & _
                              " " & TimeValue(.Start) & " - " & TimeValue(.End)
                Else
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  'Debug.Print "Non-recurring Out-of-range " & .Start & " - " & .End
                End If
              End If
            End If
          Case olApptMaster
            'Debug.Assert False
            Set RecurrPattern = .GetRecurrencePattern()
            DateStart = .Start
            DateEnd = .End
            AllDayEvent = .AllDayEvent
            Location = .Location   ' Record for recurring items
            Subject = .Subject

            'Debug.Assert Subject <> "Test recurring yearly 2 days"

            Categories = .Categories
            With RecurrPattern
              ' Not all properties have a meaningful value for all RecurrenceTypes
              ' but the value always appears to be of the correct data type.
              'Debug.Print "Recurr Pattern " & .PatternStartDate & " - " & .PatternEndDate
              'For InxE = 1 To .Exceptions.Count
              '   Debug.Print "  Exception " & InxE & " to recurring item " & " for occurrence on " & _
              '                     .Exceptions.Item(InxE).OriginalDate
              'Next

              'Debug.Assert .PatternStartDate <> #2/12/2020#

              If .PatternStartDate >= DateReportEnd Or _
                 .PatternEndDate <= DateReportStart Then
                ' All occurrences outside report range
                'Debug.Print "  All occurences out-of-range"
              Else
                ' For most recurrence types, there is a single interval. For weekly
                ' recurrences, the DayOfWeekMask there can be several intervals
                If .RecurrenceType = olRecursYearly Then
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  ' Set parameters for DateAdd
                  DateAddInterval = "yyyy"
                  ' .Interval is the interval between occurrences in months
                  DateAddNumbers = VBA.Array(.Interval / 12)
                ElseIf .RecurrenceType = olRecursYearNth Then
                  ' I cannot discover how to create an appointment item with this
                  ' RecurrenceType. Is it obsolete?
                  Debug.Assert False
                  DateAddInterval = "yyyy"
                  DateAddNumbers = VBA.Array(1)      ' #### Fix if ever get this recurrence type
                ElseIf .RecurrenceType = olRecursMonthly Then
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  DateAddInterval = "m"
                  DateAddNumbers = VBA.Array(.Interval)
                ElseIf .RecurrenceType = olRecursMonthNth Then
                  ' I cannot discover how to create an appointment item with this
                  ' RecurrenceType. Is it obsolete?
                  Debug.Assert False
                  DateAddInterval = "m"
                  DateAddNumbers = VBA.Array(1)      ' #### Fix if ever get this recurrence type
                ElseIf .RecurrenceType = olRecursWeekly Then
                  'Debug.Assert False
                  DateAddInterval = "d"   ' Step by days not weeks
                    MaskCrnt = 1
                    NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask = 0
                    ' .DayOfWeekMask is sum of 64 for Saturday, 32 for Friday, ... 1 for Sunday
                  For InxDCrnt = 0 To 6   ' Sunday to Saturday
                    If (.DayOfWeekMask And MaskCrnt) <> 0 Then
                      NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask = NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask + 1
                    End If
                    MaskCrnt = MaskCrnt + MaskCrnt  ' 1 -> 2 -> 4 ... -> 64
                  Next

                  If NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask = 1 Then
                    ' Simple one day per week mask
                    ReDim DateAddNumbers(0 To 0)
                    DateAddNumbers(0) = .Interval * 7
                  Else
                    ' .Interval is number of weeks between events
                    ' If .Interval is 1, need one value per NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask
                    ' If .Interval is >1, need one value per NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask+1
                    ReDim DateAddNumbers(0 To NumDaysInDayOfWeekMask + IIf(.Interval = 1, 0, 1) - 1)

                    ' If meetings are Tuesday and Thursday with the first meeting on a
                    ' Thursday, the intervals are 5, 2 and then 0 or 7 or 14 and so on
                    ' according to the number of weeks between meetings.
                    ' If meetings are Tuesday and Thursday with the first meeting on a
                    ' Tuesday, the intervals are 2, 5 and then 0 or 7 or 14 and so on
                    ' according to the number of weeks between meetings.
                    ' In either case, the intervals then repeat until DateCrnt is after
                    ' the report period.
                    ' Starting the check for a date being within report period from the
                    ' pattern start date will cause a delay if the pattern start date
                    ' was in the remote past.  If this happens, the start date for the
                    ' check may have to be reviewed.

                    ' Return value is 1 to 7.  Want 0 to 6 for array index
                    InxDStart = Weekday(.PatternStartDate) - 1
                    ' End day of week is day before start day of week
                    InxDEnd = IIf(InxDStart = 1, 7, InxDStart - 1)
                    InxDCrnt = InxDStart
                    IntervalNext = 1
                    InxDAN = 0
                    Do While True
                      ' Start check at day of week after start date of week.
                      ' Cycle back to zero after checking sixth day of week
                      InxDCrnt = IIf(InxDCrnt = 6, 0, InxDCrnt + 1)
                      If (DayOfWeekMaskValues(InxDCrnt) And .DayOfWeekMask) <> 0 Then
                        ' This day is within day-of-week mask
                        DateAddNumbers(InxDAN) = IntervalNext
                        InxDAN = InxDAN + 1
                        IntervalNext = 0
                      End If
                      IntervalNext = IntervalNext + 1
                      If InxDCrnt = InxDEnd Then
                        Exit Do
                      End If
                    Loop
                    DateAddNumbers(InxDAN) = IntervalNext
                    InxDAN = InxDAN + 1
                    If .Interval > 1 Then
                      DateAddNumbers(InxDAN) = (.Interval - 1) * 7
                    End If
                  End If
                ElseIf .RecurrenceType = olRecursDaily Then
                  Debug.Assert False
                  DateAddInterval = "d"
                  ' .Interval is the interval between occurrences in days
                  DateAddNumbers = VBA.Array(.Interval)
                End If

                OccurrenceInRange = False  ' Assume no occurrences in range until find otherwise
                DateCrnt = .PatternStartDate
                InxDAN = LBound(DateAddNumbers)
                Do While True
                  If DateCrnt >= DateReportStart And DateCrnt <= DateReportEnd Then
                    ' This occurrence within report range
                    OccurrenceInRange = True
                    'Debug.Print "  In range " & DateCrnt
                    ExceptionNoneForDateCrnt = True
                    For InxE = 1 To .Exceptions.Count
                      With .Exceptions.Item(InxE)
                        If DateValue(.OriginalDate) = DateCrnt Then
                          ' Have exception for this occurence
                          ExceptionNoneForDateCrnt = False
                          If .Deleted Then
                            ' Occurence deleted.
                            ' Nothing to output.
                          Else
                            ' Occurence amended
                            With .AppointmentItem
                              ExceptionAllDayEvent = .AllDayEvent
                              ExceptionDateStart = .Start
                              ExceptionDateEnd = .End
                              ExceptionSubject = .Subject
                              ExceptionLocation = Location
                              ' I cannot change the categories for an exception
                            End With
                            AppointToReport.Add Array( _
                                        CalcStartDateCrnt(ExceptionDateStart, DateCrnt, _
                                                          ExceptionAllDayEvent), _
                                        CalcEndDateCrnt(ExceptionDateStart, ExceptionDateEnd, _
                                                        DateCrnt, ExceptionAllDayEvent), _
                                        ExceptionSubject, ExceptionLocation, Categories)
                          End If
                          Exit For
                        End If
                      End With
                    Next
                    If ExceptionNoneForDateCrnt Then
                      ' No exception for this occurrence
                      AppointToReport.Add Array( _
                                    CalcStartDateCrnt(DateStart, DateCrnt, AllDayEvent), _
                                    CalcEndDateCrnt(DateStart, DateEnd, DateCrnt, AllDayEvent), _
                                    Subject, Location, Categories)
                    End If
                  ElseIf DateCrnt >= DateReportEnd Then
                    ' This occurrence is after end of report range
                    'Debug.Print "  After range " & DateCrnt
                    Exit Do
                  Else
                    ' This occurrence is before report range
                    'Debug.Print "  Before range " & DateCrnt
                  End If
                  ' Prepare for next repeat of loop
                  DateCrnt = DateAdd(DateAddInterval, DateAddNumbers(InxDAN), DateCrnt)
                  InxDAN = InxDAN + 1
                  If InxDAN > UBound(DateAddNumbers) Then
                    InxDAN = LBound(DateAddNumbers)
                  End If
                Loop
              End If
              'If OccurrenceInRange Then
              '  'Debug.Assert False
              '  Debug.Print "  StartEndDate " & DateStart & " - " & DateEnd & _
              '              " " & IIf(AllDayEvent, "All", "Part") & " day"
              '  Debug.Print "  PatternStartEndDate " & .PatternStartDate & " - " & .PatternEndDate
              '  Debug.Print "  DayOfMonth " & .DayOfMonth & " " & "MonthOfYear " & .MonthOfYear
              '  Debug.Print "  DayOfWeekMask " & .DayOfWeekMask
              '  Debug.Print "  Instance " & .Instance & " " & "Interval " & .Interval
              '  Debug.Print "  NoEndDate " & .NoEndDate
              '  Debug.Print "  Occurrences " & .Occurrences
              '  Debug.Print "  RecurrenceType " & .RecurrenceType & " ";
              '  Select Case .RecurrenceType
              '    Case olRecursYearly
              '      Debug.Print "Yearly"
              '    Case olRecursYearNth
              '      Debug.Print "YearNth"
              '    Case olRecursMonthly
              '      Debug.Print "Monthly"
              '    Case olRecursMonthNth
              '      Debug.Print "MonthNth"
              '    Case olRecursWeekly
              '      Debug.Print "Weekly"
              '    Case olRecursDaily
              '      Debug.Print "Daily"
              '  End Select
              '  Debug.Print "  StartEndTime " & .StartTime & " - " & .EndTime
              'End If
            End With  ' RecurrPattern
          Case olApptException
            Debug.Assert False
            ' Exceptions are linked to their Master calendar entry.
            ' I do not believe they exist at calendar entries
          Case olApptOccurrence
            Debug.Assert False
            ' I believe this state can only exist if GetOccurrence() is used
            ' to get a single occurrence of a Master entery. I do not believe
            ' it can appear as a calendar entry
          Case Else
            Debug.Print "Unrecognised (" & .RecurrenceState & ")"
            Debug.Assert False
        End Select
      End With  ' AppointCrnt
    End If  ' CalItemClass = olAppointment

  Next InxFC

  ' Output appointments to worksheet "Appointments"
  With Worksheets("Appointments")

    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete

    ' Create headings
    With .Cells(1, 1)
      .Value = "Start"
      .NumberFormat = "dmmmyy"
    End With
    .Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = "h:mm"
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 2))
      .Merge
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Cells(1, 3)
      .Value = "End"
      .NumberFormat = "dmmmyy"
    End With
    .Cells(1, 4).NumberFormat = "h:mm"
    With .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, 4))
      .Merge
      .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "Subject"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "Location"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Categories"
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 7)).Font.Bold = True
    RowCrnt = 2

    ' Output data rows
    For InxATR = 1 To AppointToReport.Count
      DateStart = AppointToReport(InxATR)(0)
      DateEnd = AppointToReport(InxATR)(1)
      Subject = AppointToReport(InxATR)(2)
      Location = AppointToReport(InxATR)(3)
      Categories = AppointToReport(InxATR)(4)

      .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = DateValue(DateStart)
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value = TimeValue(DateStart)
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 3).Value = DateValue(DateEnd)
      If TimeValue(DateEnd) <> 0 Then
        .Cells(RowCrnt, 4).Value = TimeValue(DateEnd)
      Else
        .Cells(RowCrnt, 4).Value = #11:59:00 PM#
      End If
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 5).Value = Subject
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 6).Value = Location
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 7).Value = Categories
      RowCrnt = RowCrnt + 1
    Next

    .Columns.AutoFit

  End With

End Sub
Function CalcStartDateCrnt(ByVal DateStart As Date, ByVal DateCrnt As Date, _
                           ByVal AllDayEvent As Boolean) As Date

  ' Calculate the start date/time for an occurrence of a recurring event

  ' DateStart     The start date/time of the first occurrence of the event
  ' DateCrnt      The date of the current occurrence
  ' AllDayEvent   True for an all day event

  If AllDayEvent Then
    CalcStartDateCrnt = DateSerial(Year(DateCrnt), Month(DateCrnt), Day(DateCrnt))
  Else
    CalcStartDateCrnt = DateSerial(Year(DateCrnt), Month(DateCrnt), Day(DateCrnt)) + _
                        TimeSerial(Hour(DateStart), Minute(DateStart), Second(DateStart))
  End If

End Function
Function CalcEndDateCrnt(ByVal DateStart As Date, ByVal DateEnd As Date, _
                         ByVal DateCrnt As Date, ByVal AllDayEvent As Boolean) As Date

   ' Calculate the end date/time for an occurrence of a recurring event

  ' DateStart     The start date/time of the first occurrence of the event
  ' DateEnd       The end date/time of the first occurrence of the event
  ' DateCrnt      The date of the current occurrence
  ' AllDayEvent   True for an all day event

  If AllDayEvent Then
    ' Times not required
    If DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(DateStart)) = DateValue(DateEnd) Then
      ' Single day event
      CalcEndDateCrnt = DateSerial(Year(DateCrnt), Month(DateCrnt), Day(DateCrnt))
    Else
      ' Multi-day event
      CalcEndDateCrnt = DateSerial(Year(DateCrnt), Month(DateCrnt), _
                                   Day(DateCrnt) + Day(DateEnd) - Day(DateStart) - 1)
    End If
  Else
    CalcEndDateCrnt = DateSerial(Year(DateCrnt), Month(DateCrnt), _
                                 Day(DateCrnt) + Day(DateEnd) - Day(DateStart)) + _
                      TimeSerial(Hour(DateEnd), Minute(DateEnd), Second(DateEnd))
  End If

End Function
```